# Why put Clustered Indexes on Identity fields?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'm just getting back into SQL Server and I'm building a few tables, and all the "guidelines" I'm reading indicate that a Clustered Index should be placed on Identity fields, because they're "ever increasing".  I'm having a hard time getting my head around this.  Let's assume I have the following data:

```
ID    Name              Date Promoted
1     John Jones        1/1/2019
2     Bill Franklin     1/15/2018
3     Tom Stewart       5/12/2020
4     Jeff Thomas       7/15/2017
```

Most of my queries will probably be based on Date Promoted.  However, I will have a table with personal identification for each person, so there will be a join to another table based on ID.

In this case, is ID the best field to have a Clustered Index on?  If so, can someone explain why in the simplest way possible?  Assume this table has 500,000 records (I'm really simplifying my problem with the sample data here), would it make sense to put a Clustered Index on Date Promoted, or would you put the Clustered on ID and a Nonclustered on Date Promoted?

Comment: With the caveat of ymmv, there are many reasons it's a good idea, but not exclusively so. if you are joining two tables then a clustered index on the joining columns will allow efficient range scans/seeks for joining the rows. You can very easily test the performance/IO overhead of having a clustered index on the `Id` column and checking the execition plan operations / Statistics IO.

Comment: What’s motivating the possibility of placing the index on `Date Promoted`? Will you be doing a lot of lookups or joins by that column? Similarly, how will the `ID` be used? Typically, you’d use the identity for foreign key constraints and, thus, joins; will that also be the case for you? Knowing nothing else about how this data will be used, I’d assume you’ll usually be querying by the `ID`, and only rarely by `Date Promoted`, but that obviously depends on your use case. Radek’s answer covers the reasoning, but these are the questions to keep in mind as you evaluate your indexes.

Comment: For instance, if this is a CRM, and this is an `Employees` table, you almost certainly want the `ID` to not only be the Clustered Index, but also the Primary Key. But if this is e.g. a view or a denormalized table for populating a calendar of promotions, then it _might_ make sense to setup `Promotion Date` as the Clustered Index—and especially if you expect `Promotion Date` to be unique. (If you don’t, you might want to _also_ want include `ID` in the Clustered Index.)

Comment: Your question - and all your research - should be focused on "how to choose the most appropriate clustered index" for your particular schema and usage. Nothing is free - most "suggestions" focus on insertion of what effectively is "random" data (has no particular pattern to the values inserted). For an employee table (or similar) i can't imagine much DML activity on that table at all and, thus, it is a poor candidate for discussion about clustering.

Comment: @SMor - It's an oversimplified example.  In reality, the tables will have dozens of fields.  My point is, if I'm mostly concerned about "What happened between Date 1 and Date 2" and never concerned about "What happened between ID 1 and ID 2", is an index on the date field a better option.  Sadly, I've forgotten much more than most will ever know, and I don't recall if indexes on date fields make sense.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: If you're doing a lot of queries based on date—such as "What happened between Date 1 and Date 2"—then having an index definitely makes sense. And if you're _primarily_ doing that type of query—as noted in my "calendar of promotions" example above—then it _might_ make sense to make it the Clustered Index. The main issue you'll run into there, [per my comment on Radek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67790283/why-put-clustered-indexes-on-identity-fields?noredirect=1#comment119824164_67790782), is that your `Promotion Date` likely isn't unique.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please note that the Clustered Index defines the order the data is stored on the disk. If you have the Clustered Index on the `Date Promoted` column then, with your sample data, inserting the fourth record would require moving all three previous records on disk. (I am simplifying this quite a bit.) As a result, that insert would be slower than an insert with the Clustered Index on the `ID` column, which would simply append a new record on disk. That is why it is best to use 'always increasing' columns.

Additionally, all non-clustered indexes contain the value(s) of the Clustered Index. So it is best to set the Clustered Index on the 'smallest' columns, when possible, in terms of consumed space. Otherwise, in the future, as the table grows, it may lead to space issues.

Finally, identity columns are commonly used for joining tables, and thus also benefit from being indexed for read performance. If your Clustered Index is on your identity column, that is already covered. Otherwise, you might need a separate index for the identity column to optimize lookups by `ID`.

Comment: It should also be noted that, while not strictly required, clustered indexes should also be _unique_ for performance reasons. If I recall, SQL Server will implicitly add a unique column if the clustered index is not unique ([source](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/effective-clustered-indexes/)). Presumably, the `Date Promoted` column will not be unique, so that’s an additional concern.